# Migration targets from meta are filtered badly

Tags: bug, migration, close-reasons, moderator-tools

I was trying to (mod-)migrate a question here on meta.cs.SE to meta.SE. But what I got was this eclectic selection of possible targets:

[image]
[image]

Note how

- most Metas are missing,
- meta.SE -- arguably *the* migration target -- is missing while
- arguably useless (for us) targets like Anime & Manga are there.
- Also, all *main* sites are available.

Clearly, something is wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, nowadays, the target selection box in the migration dialog only shows the first 10 search hits in alphabetical order. All meta sites contain the word “meta”, so if you just type `meta` then you basically get the first 10 meta sites in alphabetical order.

Variations are possible on the site name, such as adding “Stack Exchange”, or typing the URL. That's why Area 51 Discussions appears, for example: its URL is `area51.meta.stackexchange.com`.

You can get Meta.SE listed by typing a bit more, e.g. `meta s`.

Comment: Ugh... that's weird. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the site search also includes partial URL search, and since the URL for Area 51 Discussions is `area51.meta.stackexchange.com`, searching `meta` will include that. Might be the same with `ham` returning [ham.se]..